# A Question on Normal Operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $T$ be a compact operator on a Hilbert space $H$. I want to prove the following:

If there exists Orthonormal Basis from the eigen vectors of $T$, then $T$ is normal operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume a complex Hilbert space $H$. If $\{ e_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthnormal basis of $H$ with $Te_n =\lambda_n e_n$, then there is a constant $M$ such that $|\lambda_n| \le M$ for all $n$ because $T$ must be bounded, which ensures the norm converges of all vector sums in this post, such as
$$
         T x = \lim_{N} T\sum_{n=1}^{N}\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n = \lim_N\sum_{n=1}^{N}\lambda_n \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
     \langle Tx,y\rangle & =\lim_N \langle \sum_{n=1}^{N}\lambda_n\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n,y\rangle \\
    & = \lim_N\sum_{n=1}^{N}\lambda_n\langle x,e_n \rangle\langle e_n,y\rangle \\
    & = \lim_N\langle x,\sum_{n=1}^{N}\overline{\lambda_n}\langle y,e_n\rangle e_n\rangle \\
    & = \langle x,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\overline{\lambda_n}\langle y,e_n\rangle e_n\rangle
\end{align}
Hence $T^*$ is given by
$$
         T^*y = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\overline{\lambda_n}\langle y,e_n\rangle e_n
$$
Consequently,
$$
             \|Tx\|^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\lambda_n|^2|\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2 = \|T^*x\|^2.
$$
That's enough to imply $T^*T=TT^*$. (Alternatively, you can directly verify $T^*Tx = TT^*x$ for all $x$ using the known forms of $T$ and $T^*$.)

Comment: Thank you very much. But i'm wondering that the first statement: $Te_n = \lambda_n e_n$. Would you please more detail for this argument? Thank you very much.

Comment: @JohnS : You have assumed an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. $\{ e_n \}$ are the assumed eigenvectors with corresponding eigenvalues $\{ \lambda_n \}$. So $Te_n = \lambda_n e_n$. The ones with non-zero eigenvalue must be a finite or countable-infinite set.

Comment: Thanks a lot. May I ask you one more question? I could not find where the assumption "$T$ is compact" is used here. Would you please give me a comment? thanks.

Comment: @JohnS : I don't think that you do need compactness. If $T$ is bounded and has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, that should be enough. Compactness is typically used to show that a compact normal operator has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.